# Proper use of promises to return results

Tags: javascript, promise

I am using [the 'Q' library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) for promises.

Here is the scenario:

```
var results = dbContext.query(userCert.conn, dbQuery.BuildQuery(query));

var models = [];
if (!results.hasErr) {
    for (var r in results.okPacket.results) {
        var m = new model(results.okPacket.results[r]);
        models.push(m);
    }
}
userCert.conn.end(); // close db connection
```

In `dbContext.query(...)`:

```
var $Q = require('Q');

function execQuery(connection, query) {
    console.log("[backend][context] EXEC QUERY: " + query);
    $Q.nfcall(connection.query, query)
        .then(function (err, results) {
            var ret = {};
            if (err) {
                // log
                var errPkt = getErrPacket(err);
                console.log("QUERY ERROR[" + errPkt.errCode + ": " +
                errPkt.errConst + "]: " + errPkt.errMessage);
                ret = {
                    hasErr: true,
                    errPacket: errPkt
                };
            } else {
                ret = {
                    hasErr: false,
                    okPacket: {
                        resType: results.constructor.name,
                        resLength: results.length,
                        results: results
                    }
                };
            }

            // is this correct?
            return function () {
                return ret;
            };
        })
        .then(function (ret) {
            // how do I then return ret to the caller?
        })
        .done();
}
```

I'm just a little lost on the way to do this (if possible). Callbacks are okay in the lower levels of my application, but I didn't want to end up with a dish filled with callback spaghetti.

Comment: i think you want to simply return the value...

Comment: @dandavis: the `connection.query` is a database call and is asynchronous.

Comment: it depends on what/how you're passing; ex: `.then(alert)` would alert the argument returned by the function to it's left. sorry to confuse matters, looks like you got some good answers.

Answer (score 2):

With promises you just return the promise to the caller:

```
function execQuery(connection, query) {
    console.log("[backend][context] EXEC QUERY: " + query);
    return $Q.nfcall(connection.query, query)
        .then(function(results) {
            return {
                hasErr: false,
                okPacket: {
                    resType: results.constructor.name,
                    resLength: results.length,
                    results: results
                }   
            };
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            // This doesn't necessarily mean a database error because
            // all errors are caught here
            if (false /*
                TODO logic that checks if the err is not a database error
                in which case you should just rethrow
            */) {
                throw err;
            }
            var errPkt = getErrPacket(err);
            console.log("QUERY ERROR[" + errPkt.errCode + ": " +
            errPkt.errConst + "]: " + errPkt.errMessage);
            return {
                hasErr: true,
                errPacket: errPkt
            };
        });
}
```

The caller can then just use the returned promise:

```
dbContext.query(userCert.conn, dbQuery.BuildQuery(query))
    .then(function(results) {
        // It is really weird to have to check for error in the success
        // case but whatever floats your boat
        if (!results.hasErr) {
            var models = results.okPacket.results.map(function(result) {
                return new model(result);
            });
        }
    })
    .finally(function() {
        userCert.conn.end();
    })
    .done();
```

Comment: This looks useful. Still learning node-js and some of the in-built oddities. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: I've implemented this verbatim but now getting an error: 'QUERY ERROR[undefined: Object #<Object> has no method '_implyConnect']: undefined' ... :/ I'm looking at some other information though.

Comment: @IAbstract that's why you want to implement the check that rethrows in case it's a programmer error rather than database error. This will cause the process fail because of `.done()` and you can see the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Promises are still callbacks. They don't change the actual mechanism of the code. The only difference is that promises allow you to un-nest callbacks. But you're still using callbacks:

```
// regular callbacks:
do_something(function(x){
    do_something_else(function(y){
        do_last_thing();
    });
});

// with promises:
do_something()
.then(function(x){
    do_something_else();
})
.then(function(y){
    do_last_thing();
});
```

You can't return the value to the caller because the code is running asynchronously. The only difference with promises is that instead of passing IN a callback, you return an object (promise) that has a method called `then` to which you pass the callback.

Comment: I think you are missing the point, you can also unnest callbacks without promises just by naming the functions so that certainly isn't the only difference.

Comment: Well, you can do that with or without promises. So there's no difference there. The point is that the OP is assuming that promises allows you to return a value, which is not what promises do.

Comment: Everything that you can do with promises can be done without promises. Promises are just a design pattern, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Promises do allow you to return a value (the promise) which is in fact as good as the value itself for many kinds of operations. For example `var version = fs.readFileAsync("package.json").then(JSON.parse).get("version");`

Comment: @Esailija: Promises don't return a value in the same sense the OP understands it. It returns a promise. I think I've mentioned this in my answer. Pretending otherwise is just being pedantic and potentially misleading. Which is exactly the reason we still have people asking questions like this.

Comment: FWIW, I sort of understood that 'promises' return a promise with some sort of value that could indicate success/failure. I guess what I was looking for was being able to use that indicator to actually return values. I've just started looking into promises and trying to clarify the vision.

Comment: Judging from the OP's code the OP's understanding is that promises magically make your code block the execution of the program, not that you couldn't return promises (which he doesn't). And I was just pointing out one of the many actual differences between promises and callbacks; that because you can return proxy-for-something that is as good as the something itself for many kinds of operations you can write much cleaner code...

Comment: For another instance you can use the entire underscore/lodash api on a promise without having to unwrap and pass callback: `promise.then(_).call("flatten", ...).call("sort").call(...)....` and if your output mechanisms support promises (such as angular templates) you never need to call a single `.then` with any callback whatsoever. Getting it already? :)